# Mvc How safe is viewbag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

My website is built around tabs. I have one single page with multiple partial views that display each tab.

The problem im facing now is I want to loop through files that the user has uploaded and display them in one of my partial views. This requires me to send the file list as a paramater in my action like this:

```
//Uploadedfiles is a function that adds the files to a list.
var files = UploadedFiles();

return View(files);
```

Because im only using one view to display all my partial views, i get:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility+d__0`1[Delamapp.CloudStorageServices.UploadEntity]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Delamapp.Models.LoginFolder'.

This means im required to not send a model item to my index view. Now, the only thing i can think off is adding my file list to viewbag and then display them on my view. BUT.. The files require high security. How safe is viewbag? Can you for example store sensitive login information in there? Can you think off some other way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I tried viewbag and i did not like it. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a model item to your view, but the model item you are passing doesn't match the type of model that your view uses (that's what the error message says).

So you need to do one of the following:

- Modify your view to accept the model type that you are passing to it
- Put the data you want to pass into the model type that your view is expecting
- Create a new model type for both your data and for the view, and use that

In terms of security, I don't think using a view bag versus model binding really enters into the question of security. Both are just ways of passing data in between the controller and the view, and that all takes place within the ASP.NET process (perhaps you have ViewBag confused with Web Forms' ViewState?).